# TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader consumes more memory

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, eclipselink

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esozc.png)I am using Eclipse MAT to analyze OutOfMemoryError(PermGen Space) and I could see Top most consumer is TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader. The project is developed using Spring and JPA(EclipseLink) . In applicationContext.xml we have InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. To make use of this load time weaving, we are using TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader. But 31.12% memory is consumed by TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader.

How to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: And is that an issue? Or is it an issue that it consumes 31%... The class loader contains all classes loaded so I doubt there is something you can do about that. Also on a totaal of 100M it would still be only 31M.

Comment: If you're adding instrumentation, that has a cost (both in terms of execution time and in terms of memory that it is using). If you need to reduce that, either remove the instrumentation or make it more targetted. In any case, that's really unlikely to be the right solution - look elsewhere to find your problems and ignore the classloader - or run it without the classloader and see if you can identify memory problems that way.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. Since  we are weaving, we cannot skip tomcat instrumentation. Is there any other way ?.

Comment: Hi , please click at the link beginning of my question,"enter image description here" , you will be able to see the attached image.

Comment: Why can't you skip weaving?  Check out static weaving if dynamic weaving is an issue.   Otherwise, you'll need to find the baseline memory requirements of the TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader class by pairing down your application and see how much it needs.  It could just be that you have an application that requires a large amount of memory to support.   See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Comment: Thank you so much Chris for the link. It works for me.. Thank u.

Comment: Hello Chris, Thank you so much for your comment and it worked for  me. Now it seems instead of TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader , WebappClassLoader consuming more memory. Could you please help me?.